# Increase speed of JAVA program for Machine Learning

Tags: java, operating-system, nlp, ram, heap-memory

I am doing machine learning in java using GATE Learning. I have a huge data set of documents to learn from. While using netbeans, I was getting java heap space error. So I provided 1600MB in the -Xmx parameter. Now, I do not get the heap space error but it takes ample of time to run!! (runs for 90 mins and I had to stop the process since I lost my patience!).

I do not understand whether I should increase my RAM(currently 4GB) or upgrade my OS(currently XP SP3, I have heard vista and win 7 better utilize RAM and Processor) or upgrade my processor(currently Dual Core E5500 2.80 GHz)?

Please throw some insight into what I can do to make this process run faster!

Thanks Rishabh

Comment: GATE provides processes to learn from those documents. I just initialize the process in my code. So don't have much idea about the internal working.

Comment: What's the size of the dataset, and what does GATE call the learning algorithm?

Comment: currently is 145 documents, summing upto 1mb on disk. I am using chunk learning with PAUM engine.

Comment: That's not a *huge* dataset, that's a pretty small one. If that really takes GATE 90mins to learn from on a modern machine, then it's time to find another ML package. I've seen similar tasks on much larger datasets complete in minutes.

Comment: ohhh ok, which learning package have you used? Also, GATE used 90 mins for SVM engine and while just now I was using PAUM on 200 docs, it completed the process in 35 mins. Do you consider even this too much time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before you can answer what will make it run faster, you have to find the bottleneck.

I'm not very familiar with Windows, but there is some sort of system load monitoring widget, IIRC.

What I would do is as follows:

- Create some datasets of increasing sizes (more documents)
- Run your program against those datasets
- On each run, work out if the CPU maxes out, or if the memory maxes out and starts swapping, or if the whole thing is IO bound

Then fix the one that is causing the problem.

Just for context, it's not that unusual for ML algorithms to take a long time to run on large data sets. You can use the above approach to plot out the run time as the size of the input datasets increase, at least then you'll know if your program would have stopped in 100 minutes or 100 centuries.

Comment: Thx a lot, but when I tried giving more heap space to the program keeping the data set size same, I did not find the process being faster. That is what I want to achieve. I don't have any constraint for adding more resources.

Comment: How did you measure it being faster? I thought you terminated it before it finished?

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding, the process that I terminated was different one. When I was running same program in a different way, it took same time to display the results even when I increased the heap space. I thought that the same process should complete faster(as netbeans gives the total time it was running for) if I dedicate more resources. So that is what I meant b4 :)

Answer (score 1):

Get a Profiler such as [VisualVM](http://visualvm.java.net/) or [YourKit](http://www.yourkit.com/) - start your programm - connect the Profiler to your running program - Find out, which methods and objects are your bottleneck - then at least you know where to start improving your program.